# Android custom view doesn't render itself

Tags: android, android-view

I am creating a custom view which extends a linear layout and just adds some views to that linear layout at some horizontal space from one another.

At first I created it like that:

```
public BarsControl(Context context)
{
    super(context);
    setValues(null);
}

public BarsControl(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
{
    super(context, attrs);
    setValues(attrs);
    addBars();
}

public BarsControl(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr)
{
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    setValues(attrs);
    addBars();
}

public BarsControl(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes)
{
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    setValues(attrs);
    addBars();
}
```

the `addBars` method is what creating all the views and adding it to the linear layout.

When I did it like the above, everything worked fine.

After that, I wanted to change the space between the views according to the actual width of the view. My thought was that if the user has set the width to be `wrap_content` then nothing would change, but if he had set it to `match_parent` then the space needs to grow. So what I did was adding this method:

```
@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh)
{
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    spaceBetweenBarsPixels = (int) ((w - barWidth * numberOfBars) / numberOfBars);
    addBars();
}
```

(Does the spaceBetweenBarsPixels seems correct to you?)

but now after adding this, the layout won't render at all unless I'm doing something which directly affects it and make it redraw itself after the app is already running.

How can I make the view draw itself based on its actual size?

Note - I can't just take the parent's width from `onMeasure` and use it since I don't know if the user set the width to `match_parent` or not.

Comment: Is it possible to see the `addBars` method implementation too?

Comment: @marino it just creates new view in a loop, set its background, gives it a LinearLayoutParams with margins of spaceBetweenBarsPixels and then just call for addView

Comment: Ok. `spaceBetweenBarsPixel` seems correct, but to have that working you should then call `invalidate()` or `redraw()` method when you add again your bars. Since it's a LinearLayout a better way would be to set a `weightSum` (equal to the number of the views you'll add in `addBars`) to the `BarsControl` layout, and then set `weight=1` and `gravity center` to each bar. This should keep them centered and equally distributed in your layout, without even calculate spacing!

Comment: Do you tried out the proposed solution? I'm curious to know if that works :)

Comment: It seems that the invoking of addBars in the onSizeChanged caused the issue. I no longer override that method at all